# Use Normal Model to approximate the Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Each item produced in a certain factory is , independently, of acceptable quality with probability $0.95$. Approximate using a normal random variable the probability that at most 9 of the next 200 items are unacceptable.

Let $X$ equal to the number of items that are unacceptable.

Do I need the continuity correction here?

Should I set up the question as $P(X\leq9)$ or $P(X\leq10)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard advice is to use the continuity correction. We are approximating the probability that our random variable is $\le 9$. So we find the probability that the approximating normal (mean $10$, standard deviation $\approx 3.08$) is $\le 9.5$.

Nowadays, the calculator or computer makes it relatively easy to calculate probabilities for the binomial distribution *exactly*. Such a calculation gives that the required probability is close to $0.4547$.

I believe that you will find that with the continuity correction, the normal approximation is pretty good. Without the continuity correction, not so good.

Comment: You are welcome. The continuity correction is somewhat a rule of thumb. One can produce examples in which using it gives a less accurate result than not using it. But in general it works fairly well.